# My background image keeps disappearing when I set div height to 100vh

Tags: javascript, html, css

[Why my dev tools shows that I have background image none on header container. It doesnt appear in VS Code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2m9w.png)

My header background image just shows for a second and then it disappears. That only happens when I set my div haight to 100vh.

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    font-family: 'Barlow', sans-serif;
}

.header{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url("images/image-header.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Barlow:wght@600&family=Fraunces:wght@700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Sunnyside Agency</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <h1 class="logo">sunnyside</h1>
        <ul>
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Services</li>
            <li>Projects</li>
            <li><button>Contact</button></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="main"></div>
    <div class="bott"></div>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to place image somewhere else, and to change image. I have the same problem with other images too.

Comment: Please could you put up a working snippet which shows the problem? As it stands what we can see of your code is not giving the problem. Also, have you checked in your browser dev tools inspect factility to see exactly who/where is 'hiding' (or overwriting) that background?

Comment: Is it the correct path to the images? You need to check that in dev tools.

Comment: if it shows up and disappears it's not a path issue

Answer (score 0):

Its working just fine, But it seems that the image path you put is wrong.

Check out the example below I only changed the Image

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    font-family: 'Barlow', sans-serif;
}

.header{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url("https://www.industrialempathy.com/img/remote/ZiClJf-1920w.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Barlow:wght@600&family=Fraunces:wght@700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Sunnyside Agency</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <h1 class="logo">sunnyside</h1>
        <ul>
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Services</li>
            <li>Projects</li>
            <li><button>Contact</button></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="main"></div>
    <div class="bott"></div>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I open dev tools it shows that I have style="background-image: none;" in my header element, but it doesnt shows in VS Code.